# Ideal top-level slug methods

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules, slug

Right now I have a post type that generates a slug, e.g. http://url.com/l/abcd/ for each entry. I have a query in my `404.php` that checks for http://url.com/abcd before output and redirects it if found in that post type "l"... What I'm wondering is, since `404.php` will always send a 404 http header, is it not ok to do 301 inside `404.php` (before any "output" starts)? It "works", but I suspect there is a better way...

Is it a bad idea to do a new `rewrite_rule()` for every slug in that post type? Is there a way to make post type "l" be top-level or checked "along with" page slugs?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are doing it right. If you will add a rule per entry you will slow down the whole URL parsing, especially for pages.

About the 404. If you are actually redirecting, then it means that you don't send a 404 as there can be only one return code.

Comment: i actually just did some trial and error and noticed that wp already 301's http://url.com/abcd  to  http://url.com/l/abcd/ automatically, so i guess i will just put the final destination redirect in the single-l.php  template file.  also, i noticed that on another site that i did this sort of redirect on 404.php before get_header() and then i use a 404 header check (http://404checker.com/) i get 404 Not Found even though the actual redirect occurs... so that is what prompted my question here.

Comment: That is strange, do you have an example to a page that both returns 404 and redirect?